# gate equivalence table?

Tags: digital-logic

I am looking for an official reference for "gate equivalence".  I have 2 conflicting values for gate equivalence for a flip-flop from 2 different books, and no GE for a mux.  My question: Is there a standard table for this anywhere?  In a paper I'm reviewing, I'm trying to figure out how a FPGA implementation of an algorithm has a lower "gate equivalence" than a custom CMOS version.

As gate equivalence is based on a NAND.  Can I just take the number of transistors, divide by 4 and get a gate equivalence number?  This whole metric seems totally meaningless to me as I cannot find how this comparison is officially made.  Google failed me so I figured I'd try to crowd source the answer.

Comment: It's fairly close to meaningless, especially when you start using BlockRams... I'd suggest counting LUTs, counting FFs, listing BlockRams and DSP/multipliers separately, and calling it done.

Comment: "Gate equivalence" is just a marketing tool, and has no real relevance for serious work. The only thing that matters in the end is whether you have used up the *actual* resources (LUTs, FFs, RAMs, routing resources, etc.) of any particular chip with your actual design.

Comment: Okay, I'm all in for "meaningless" aspect of this.  I will make a note to justify the numbers or remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use transistor numbers as a comparative measure, but you definitely shouldn't call it "gate equivalency". For your goals, you would be best served using measures of *circuit complexity*, namely **circuit size** and **circuit depth** ([Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity)).

First of all, comparison should follow certain boundaries (so that conclusions drawn can be meaningful): each gate must have a maximum fan-in (this should be ideally between 2 and 4) and the number of allowed gate types must be limited (tipycally only ANDs, ORs and NOTs, but you could opt for only NANDs as well).

**Circuit size** is then the minimum number of gates in each circuit, and **circuit depth** is the longest path (in number of gates) from a digital input to a digital output.

To analyse the flip-flops and MUX you have mentioned, you must first expand them in logic gates following the same boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts, but I'm well capable of analyzing anything.  I just wanted the communities thoughts on the metric as it seemed worthless, and indeed it is.  I've decided that it's all moonshine.